# Building a Bing Store Locator

Tags: geolocation, bing-maps

I've tried Google but I'm not smart enough to build my own Google Store locator. Everything is either old or in PHP and I use Python. Even GAE uses Python but I can't find any tutorials for Python at all. I even had a bounty here on S.o. for resources to a Python store locator and the only answer had a post from 2008 that was updated to "deprecated" on the post itself.

So I decided to give Bing a try and it has more noob options, such as "enter address here" and then it's listed in the app. The only problem is that everything is pointing me to Bing Spacial Datasend and it says they want to charge an arm and a leg.

Also, if you know of any, are there any good tutorials on building a Bing Store Locator? Google search has come up empty for me but they could always be hiding them. Thanks.

Comment: Are these *your* stores that you're trying to locate (i.e. you have a dataset of the locations of stores in a database or something similiar), or are you trying to create an app that lets users search Bing's database of stores/restaurants etc.?

Comment: These are my stores. Right now I've just been manually inserting them into the Google service so there is no search functionality. I know that I need a database for that and Bing, but I could never find Google python app to even get started. With Bing, I immediately saw that service that seems to make it easy, but then it led me to the Bind Spacial Data Set that looks like it costs. But yes, I do have the stores in a database. SQLite to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have less than 50 locations you can use the Bing Spatial Data Services under the free terms of use. If your application is a public facing web site, which most store locators are you can also generate 125,000 transactions against Bing Maps for free per year. If this is enough or not would depend on the number of stores and customers you have. The Bing Spatial Data Services is a really good option as you simply upload your data and it exposes it as a spatial rest service for you which you can access directly from JavaScript without the need for any server side code. Here is an example of how to query a data source in the Bing Spatial Data Services: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#SpatialDataServices1

If your application has a lot more volume then you would need a Bing Maps license. The cost of a license varies depending on the amount of transactions your application will use. If you have a Bing Maps license data sources can have up to 600,000 locations in a single data source and each Bing Maps account is allowed up to 25 data sources.

Comment: lol I think 2 years ago when I asked this question this might not have been an option. Thanks for posting though since someone might stumble upon this and find it helpful. I can't remember but I think I went in another direction. Thanks again for your answer and now you get that sweet Necromancer badge.

Comment: This solution would of worked 2 or 3 years ago. I have been mainly focusing answering questions on the official Bing Maps forums in MSDN and only recently started cleaning up the Bing Maps posts in stackoverflow. I figured you had figured out a solution by now but as you mentioned this might be useful for someone else.

Comment: I'll accept although I can't verify. You seem to know what you're talking about, though so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. Cheers.